# How to mute Datadog monitor for warnings only?

Tags: datadog

I have a number of servers, each running a single instance of a number of services where those servers are behind a load balancer (e.g. each server runs services A, B and C). There is a Datadog HTTP check for each of those service instances. The servers are rebooted on a weekly schedule, where the reboots are staggered.

I want to have a monitor that is in warning status if any instance of any of the services is not available. I want to have an alert when there are no instances of a particular service available.

The query looks like this:

```
avg(last_5m):sum:network.http.can_connect{app:foo} by {env, svc} < 1
```

I can schedule downtime for the monitor for each of the reboot periods, but that will mute the monitor for all statuses (i.e. it'll mute both warnings and alerts). I don't care if I lose X servers in the group during a reboot period, but I really, really care that there is always at least Y servers available.

Is there a way of specifying the downtime muting according to the status of the monitors, or is there another way I should be structuring the monitor (which could be by using a completely different Datadog metric)?